# How to open the Facebook app during OAuth in Ionic?

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework

I just got my app working with `$cordovaOAuth` from [ng-cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) and I've read and understood all from Nic Raboy's post (http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/). It works fine: both the inAppBrowser and the authentication itself.

But I want to take it one step further: how can I redirect the OAuth call to the installed app itself? For example, if I was using Facebook OAuth, how can I open the actual Facebook app (if installed - how to check it?) instead of a browser?

Comment: Not sure if directly relevant, but you can authenticate using the native Facebook app with [ngCordova's `$cordovaFacebook`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll see the code and check if it is possible to port it to other OAuth providers.

Comment: You might wan to look into URL schemes if you are working with iOS: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Comment: $cordovaOauth is sandboxed from other applications.  You would have to use a different plugin or modify the ng-cordova-oauth source to accommodate your needs.